# how can i change the font weight into a scrolled text from the fla?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs4

i would like to modify the font weight of a word (my title) that is into a textfield that is "scrolled" : so when i modify this word, the whole text is being modified as well, and i can't write it in another textfield, because i want it to be scrolled as the rest of the text.

Do i "have to" set the title and the text dynamically to change the font? or can i do it directly from the fla (which would save me some time, i have several texts in the same case)

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set textfield to use html markup and set your title as bold:

```
<b>My title</b>
...rest of text, regular font
```

Comment: thanks Bartek, do you mean directly from the fla, or from the .as ?

Comment: If you use only fla, you can write your text into textfield directly, select title and then change font for your selection (ie bold style). When using as3 try `myTextField.htmlText = "<b>asd</b>asdasd";`

Comment: thanks Bartek, yeah i don't know why this does not work, i tried to select directly the text in the fla but this updates the whole text. If i fill the textfield from the .as, i have to load a xml file right? because it seems that flash doesn't like the line breaks... or if you know any better solution? thanks